# mySQL UPDATE REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to replace special characters in a mysql table:

for example: Ã¼ to become ü

```
UPDATE contacts SET name = REPLACE(name, "Ã¼", "ü")
```

This query doesn't work for these but works for let's say M to become L.

How to get this working with this type of characters?

Comment: How have you verified to begin with that the database _actually_ contains `Ã¼`? What's the character encoding used by the connection, and where from are you firing this statement (phpMyAdmin, your own script, ...)?

Comment: @CBroe for Storage Engine is InnoDB and collation is UTF8_unicode_ci, I tried both phpMyAdmin and my own PHP script, both don't work.

Comment: @CBroe When viewing in phpMyAdmin it shows the character as is "KÂ¼hn"